# No se ejecuta el javascript completamente: problema de javascript, formulario o del echo?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Tengo dos grupos de checkbox que se llenan con base de datos y tengo una funcion javascript que los borra cuando se cambia un radiobutton (hay un radio button para mostrar cada grupo de checkbox), creo que estan dando problemas porque ni siquiera puedo hacer un alert dentro del sistema, a pesar que algunas funciones javascript si funcionan, por ejemplo el limite de checkbox, pero al querer ejecutar dentro del formulario otros javascript no funcionan.

que puede ser?

funcion e limite de checkbox (Funcionand - SIN ALERT)

```
function validacionMaximo(input) {
  limite=3;
  seleccionados=0;
  if (input.checked) {
    for (i=0; ele=input.form.elements[i]; i++)
      if (ele.checked) seleccionados++;
  if (seleccionados>limite){
          alert("No puede seleccionar mas de dos elementos");
    input.checked=false;
  }

   }
}
```

funcion de borrar (sin funcionar)

```
function borrar(){
var cf = document.getElementsByName('atenuantes[]');
var cs = document.getElementsByName('agravantes[]');

for (i=0; i<cf.length; i++){
if(cf[i].checked = true){
cf[i].checked = false;
}
}

for (i=0; i<cs.length; i++){
if(cs[i].checked = true){
cs[i].checked = false;
}
}
}
```

ya trate crando los checkbox manualmente y no pasa nada

trate tambien de crear un archivo de prueba.js con `function prueba(){alert("hola");}` y tampoco se ejecuta

aqui el formulario:

```
<?php
   session_start();
   // CONECTANDO AL SISTEMA SEGUN TIPO DE USUARIO//
   if (isset($_SESSION['conectado'] ) && $_SESSION['conectado'] == true && $_SESSION['nivel']==1) {
   require_once '__conexion.php';
   include 'encabezado.php';
   include 'funciones/JSON.php';
   include 'funciones_php_generarSelects.php';
   // ------------------------ //
   } else {
   // MENSAJE DE ACCESO NEGADO //
   echo ('<script>alert("No tiene permisos suficientes para acceder a esta parte del sistema");</script>');
   echo ("<script>window.location = 'index.php';</script>");
   exit;
   // ------------------------ //
   }
   // ------------------------ //
   $now = time();
   if($now > $_SESSION['expira']) {
   //DESTRUYO LA SESION, ANTES DE SACARLO DEL SISTEMA//
   session_destroy();
   // MENSAJE DE SESIÓN EXPIRADA //
   echo ('<script>alert("Su sesión ha expirado");</script>');
   echo ("<script>window.location = 'index.php';</script>");
   exit;
   }
   // ------------------------ //
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Sistema Automatizado de Orden de Medida Disciplinaria</title>

      <!-- Librerias -->
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
      <!-- ///////// -->

      <!-- Funciones -->
      <script src="funciones/circunstancias_borrar.js"></script>
      <script src="funciones/circunstancias_cambio.js"></script>
      <script src="funciones/circunstancias_limite.js"></script>
      <script src="funciones/circunstancias_refrescado.js"></script>
      <script src="funciones/circunstancias_verificar.js"></script>
      <script src="funciones/validar_longitud.js"></script>
      <!-- FALTA VALIDAR LA OMD -->
      <!-- ///////// -->
      <!-- Hojas de Estilo -->
      <link rel='stylesheet' href='recursos/css/estilo.css'>
      <!-- /////////////// -->

</head>
<body onload="refrescado()">
<form id="omd" name="omd" method="POST" action="funciones/generarOMD.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">


   <table width="593" border="3" align="center">
   <tr>
   <div>
   Ingrese el n&uacute;mero de cedula del sancionado: 
   <input type="text" id="cedula1" name="cedula1" oncopy="return false" onpaste="return false">
   <input type="text" name="resultado1" id="resultado1" readonly>
   </div>

   <div>
   Ingrese el n&uacute;mero de cedula del sancionador: 
   <input type="text" id="cedula2" name="cedula2" oncopy="return false" onpaste="return false">
   <input type="text" name="resultado2" id="resultado2" readonly>

   <div>
   Ingrese el n&uacute;mero de cedula del superior: 
   <input type="text" id="cedula3" name="cedula3" oncopy="return false" onpaste="return false">
   <input type="text" name="resultado3" id="resultado3" readonly>

   <div>   
   Seleccione el art&iacute;culo inflingido: 
   <select name="articulo" id="articulo">
   <option value="0">Seleccione un articulo:</option>
   <?php
   listaArticulos();
   ?>
   </select>

   <div> 
   Seleccione el apartado: 
   <select id="apartado" name="apartado">
   <option value="0">Seleccione primero un art&iacute;culo</option>
   </select>

   <div> 
   Decripci&oacute;n de la falta:
   <input type="text" id="desc_falta" name="desc_falta" readonly>
   </div>

   <div> 
   Seleccione el tipo de circunstancia influyente: 
   <input type="radio" name="tipo_circunstancia" id="ninguno"              onclick="toggle(this); borrar()"   value ="0" checked > Ninguno 
   <input type="radio" name="tipo_circunstancia" id="tipo_atenuante"       onclick="toggle(this); borrar()"   value="1"> Atenuantes 
   <input type="radio" name="tipo_circunstancia" id="tipo_circunstancia"   onclick="toggle(this); borrar()"   value="2"> Agravantes <br/>
   </div>     

   <div id="uno">
   Circunstancias Atenuantes:
   <?php
   listaAtenuantes();
   ?>
   </div>

   <div id="dos">
   Circunstancias Agravantes:
   <?php
   listaAgravantes();
   ?>
   </div>  

   <div>    
   Seleccione el estado: 
    <select>
    <option value="0">Seleccione un estado</option>
    <?php
   listaEstados();
   ?>
    </select>
   </div>

   <div>      
   Seleccione los documentos anexos: 
   <?php
   echo "Documentos Anexos: ";
   listaDocumentos();
   ?>
   </div>

   <div>
   <p><STRONG>NOTA:</STRONG>
   Cabe destacar que debe poseer <br>todos los documentos de<br> manera fisica
   de lo contrario<br>, su orden de medida <br>disciplinaria sera remitida con un
   oficio de devolución</p>
   </div>

   <div>
   Ingrese la fecha del &uacute;ltimo ascenso
   <input type="text" name="fecha_ascenso" readonly id="datepicker1">
   </div>

   <div>
   Ingrese el cargo actual del sancionado: 
   <input type="text" name="cargo" id="cargo">
   </div>   

   <div>
   Seleccione el tipo de medida disciplinaria:
   <select name="medida">
   <option value="0">Seleccione una medida</option>
   <?php
   listaMedidas();
   ?>
   </select>
   </div>

   <div>
   Ingrese el n&uacute;mero de d&iacute;as de la OMD: 
   <input type="text" name="dias" id="dias">
   <p><STRONG>NOTA:</STRONG>
   Las fechas de la OMD se calcularan automaticamente, despues de ingresar el n&uacute;mero de d&iacute;as.
   </div>

   <div>
   Fecha de inicio de la OMD: 
   <input type="text" name="fecha_inicio" readonly value="<?php echo $fecha_inicio=date('d-m-Y');?>">
   </div>

   <div>
   fecha de termino de la OMD: 
   <input type="text" name="fecha_fin" readonly id="datepicker3" >
   </div>

   <div>
   Aclaratoria de la falta: 
   <textarea cols="40" rows="5" name="aclaratoria" onKeyDown="valida_longitud()" onKeyUp="valida_longitud()" onBlur="aMays(event, this)"></textarea>
   Car&aacute;cteres ingresados / disponibles: 
   <input type="text" name="caracteres" size=4><input type="text" name="caracteres2" size=4>
   </div>  
   </tr>      
   </table> <!-- TABLA DEL ESTANDAR-->




      <table class="fin" align="center">
         <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="enviar">
            <center><img width="50" height="50" onclick="location.href='funciones/generarOMD.php';" src="recursos/iconos/guardar.png" alt="GUARDAR"/>Guardar
            <img width="50" height="50" onclick="location.href='menu_unidades.php';" src="recursos/iconos/salir.png" alt="SALIR"/>Atras</center>
            </td>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Aqui los checkbox

```
    function listaAtenuantes()
          {
          global $conexion;
          global $conexion;
          $stmt = $conexion->prepare("SELECT id_aparte,desc_circunstancia FROM circunstancias WHERE id_articulo=40");
          $stmt->execute();
          $stmt->store_result();
          $numfilas = $stmt->num_rows;

          // echo $numfilas;

          $stmt->get_result(); //obtener los resultados
          $stmt->bind_result($stmt1, $stmt2); //asignarlos a las variables, cada variable debe ser un campo que obtengo del query
          while ($stmt->fetch())
                {
                echo "</br>" . "<input type='checkbox' onclick='validacionMaximo(this);' name='atenuantes[]' value='" . $stmt1 . "'>" . $stmt2;
                }
          }

function listaAgravantes()
      {
      global $conexion;
      global $conexion;
      $stmt = $conexion->prepare("SELECT id_aparte,desc_circunstancia FROM circunstancias WHERE id_articulo=41");
      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt->store_result();
      $numfilas = $stmt->num_rows;

      // echo $numfilas;

      $stmt->get_result(); //obtener los resultados
      $stmt->bind_result($stmt1, $stmt2); //asignarlos a las variables, cada variable debe ser un campo que obtengo del query
      while ($stmt->fetch())
            {
            echo "</br>" . "<input type='checkbox'  onclick='validacionMaximo(this);' name='agravantes[]' value='" . $stmt1 . "'>" . $stmt2;
            }
      }
```

Comment: El inspector te muestra algún error?

Comment: la consola(F12) nada, de repente todo los codigos js empezaron a dejar de servir, luego me di cuenta de que faltaba una > en un link y sirvieron, luego, no volvieron a servir mas y no se porque, probe con phpfiddle y deja de mostrar contenido hasta donde dice "articulo inflingido" sera eso?

Comment: En tu JS: `var cf = document.getElementsByName('atenuantes[]');` y en tu funcion `listaAtenuantes`: `echo "</br>" . "<input type='checkbox' onclick='validacionMaximo(this);' name='atenuantes[]' value='" . $stmt1 . "'>" . $stmt2;` ¿por qué asignas una variable de tipo array **`atenuantes[]`
** al nombre? El nombre es para darle un nombre, no para almacenar valores. Lo mismo ocurre con **agravantes[]**

Comment: una cosa, cuando reviso la consola salen los archivos usados y solo se muestran los viejos???, porque ocurre eso, me ha pasado que he podido ejecutar funciones js incluso luego de haber borrado el archivo

Comment: mi archivo circunstancias-borrar: function borrar(){
var cf = document.getElementsByName('atenuantes[]');
var cs = document.getElementsByName('agravantes[]');
 
for (i=0; i<cf.length; i++){
if(cf[i].checked = true){
cf[i].checked = false;
}
}
 
for (i=0; i<cs.length; i++){
if(cs[i].checked = true){
cs[i].checked = false;
}
}
}

Comment: el archivo del inspector. 
function borrar(){
var cf = document.getElementsByName('comida_fuerte[]');
var cs = document.getElementsByName('comida_sopa[]');
 
for (i=0; i<cf.length; i++){
if(cf[i].checked = true){
cf[i].checked = false;
}
}
 
for (i=0; i<cs.length; i++){
if(cs[i].checked = true){
cs[i].checked = false;
}
}
}

Comment: Puede ser que estén en caché, por eso te salen archivos viejos. Prueba actualizar con Ctrl + Shift + R.

Comment: jajajaajajaj funciono, hace horas habia quitado el fondo del documnento y seguia apareciendo

Comment: TE AMO :) jajaja

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema parece que es el almacenamiento en caché y sigues utilizando archivos viejos.

Prueba refrescando la página con `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `R`.

Answer (score 1):

Los elementos **atenuantes[]** y **agravantes[]** tienen caracteres invalidos para la busqueda en el DOM. Te recomiendo renombrarlos son los **[]**. La funcion JS *getElementByName* te devuelve un array de objetos que contengan ese nombre.

De este modo, buscarías:

```
var cf = document.getElementsByName('atenuantes');
var cs = document.getElementsByName('agravantes');
```

Y podrías recorrerlos de la misma manera que ahora. 
Espero te sea de utilidad.

Éxitos!

Comment: te comparto que al revisar el inspector del navegador sale el preview de los codigos y son puros archivos viejos, y como comentaba arriba, me ha pasado que puedo usar funciones que ya estan borradas

Comment: como lo tengo funcionaba, pero si me pude dar cuenta que el inspector arrojaba un error de htmlinputelement

Comment: gracias igual por la correción, puedes pasarte por mis otras preguntas y con gusto recibo tu ayuda

Comment: @VictorA. puedes probar declarando el bloque SCRIPT como defer??

Comment: como se usa eso del defer

Comment: se agrega como info en el tag script:  <script src="libreria.js" defer></script>. Este atributo hace que el script sólo se ejecute una vez cargado todo el DOM.

Comment: te comento que ese cambio que le hice al script evito que funcionara, pues realmente los nombres son atenuantes[] y agravantes[] pues ambos son arrays, trate de usar el script hoy y no recorria los arrays, por eso lo deje como estaba, claro esta tu respuesta tambien tiene logica, pero no me queria funcionar

Comment: @VictorA. no va a funcionar si no cambias también el nombre del origen. Si la variable PHP es un array, cuando lo asignas como valor a la propiedad _name_, pierde su condicion de array y pasa a convertirse simplemente a un string de referencia. Por tanto, no es necesario que pases el nombre del array como está definido en PHP.

Comment: los cambie a atenuantes[] y agravantes[] y funciono perfectamente, incluso me genero problemas mas adelante y tuve que cambiarlo (esta puesto en otro pregunta)

Answer (score -1):

Si trabajas con PHP puro, una solución es renombrar el archivo cada vez que te pase eso. Ese problema es con js solamente. Es estresante, pero eso es lo más fácil que pude encontrar.

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]